# what are the mistake in this code, its giving me NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why this code giving me NaN as an output???

```js
var rob = function(nums) {
  var a = 0;
  var b = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    a += nums[i] + nums[i + 2]
    b += nums[i + 1] + nums[i + 2]
  }
  return a
};
console.log(rob([1, 2, 3, 1]));
```

Comment: What do you think `nums[i + 2]` would give for `i = 3`? Also see: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Answer (score 0):

You iterate through the array `nums` and then trying to access its members beyond its last element.

When `i` is `3`, `nums[i+2]` refers to nonexisting element, yielding `undefined`, and when you add a number to `undefined`, you get `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

There are four items in the array `[1, 2, 3, 1]`. The issue is `i+2`.

In third iteration of the loop, you are trying to access an index that doesn't exist: `nums[i + 2]` in third iteration becomes `nums[2 + 2]`, which becomes `nums[4]`. But `nums[3]` is the last item, because the array length is only 4

Answer (score 0):

When `i`, the index of the array `nums` is out of bounds `nums[i]` is `undefined`. And when you add any `undefined` to any number or `NaN` the result is `NaN`.

You can use `nums[i+2] || 0` and `nums[i+1] || 0` to avoid dealing with `undefined`. If your aim is to sum all elements with an even index, 0,2 ..., and put the result in `a`, a better approach might be as below. For a larger array you run the danger of adding some elements to the result more than once.

However, if that's your goal then you can retain `nums[+2] || 0` and `nums[i+1] || 0`.

```js
const rob = function(nums) {
  let a = 0;
  let b = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i = i + 2) {
    a += nums[i];
    b += nums[i+1] || 0;
  }
  return a;
};
console.log(rob([1, 2, 3, 1]));
```